# Datagrid does not updated automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, desktop-application

I want to imlement mvvm pattern in a wpf application,

So i have created three project
One is wpf app an dother two are class library,

I have initialized the datacontext to the view model in the constractor of Mainwindow,

And in view model i have create an observable collection of tl'Students'
, i also Implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface,
But when i add or remove a student
The changes efect the database
But the is not updated automatically

What i should do?

I have tried alot in youtube,
And google
But there i could't find a three layer project to solve this problem.

Comment: @Sadat, could you share reproducible snippets of your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot believe your description, does your ViewModel class looks like this? Maybe you just missing the private field.

Remember binding Grid.ItemSource with ModelItems.

```
    private ObservableCollection<Model> modelItems;

    public ObservableCollection<Model> ModelItems
    {
        get { return modelItems; }
        set
        {
            modelItems= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ModelItems");
        }
    }        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes Exactly like this, But I have set the DataContext in the Constructor of MainWindow.xaml.cs    DataContext = new Model.Student();     and the ItemSource of dataGrid to observablecollection like  ItemSource ={binding Students}

Comment: Is Model.Student() the viewModel class with  ObservableCollection<StudentModel> Students property? And StudentModel should also implement INotifyChanged interface.

Comment: Be sure the ItemsSource="{Binding Students,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" and grid already has a customed ItemTemplate.

Comment: Ok, thanks alot, i just implement Singleton design pattern in the viewmodel now its working.

Comment: If there are more than 1 views using diffierent viewmodel objects, you should design a sessioncontext or something else to share the data , and raise updated event when collection changed to notify these viewmodels. Or using Ioc container register the viewmodel object as singleton, and resolve to these views.